# remove tag but keep string between tag in php

Tags: php, string, tags

I have file which get content from my other site. It is clude lot of:

```
<script>
[random] string 1
</script>

<script>
[random] string 2
</script>
....
<script>
[random] string n
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
must keeping script
</script>

<script type=text/javascript'>
must keeping script
</script>
```

I want to REMOVE `<script>` and `</script>` but KEEP content between them "[random] string ..." using PHP.

Note: str_replace can remove them but may make hurst other scripts `<script type="text/javascript">must keeping</script>` and `<script type='text/javascript'>must keeping</script>`.
It will lost close tag `</script>` of must keeping script

Thanks for helping

//SOLVED with:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<script>)(.*?)(<\/script>)/s', '$2', $content);
```

Anyway, thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$content = "
    <script>
    [random] string 1
    </script>

    <script>
    [random] string 2
    </script>
    ....
    <script>
    [random] string n
    </script>    
";

$content = str_replace(array("<script>", "</script>"), "", $content);
```

EDIT:
Since you want to get rid of `<script></script>` and in the same time keep `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` and because using regexp to solve this kind of problems [is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) then try to use the `DOMDocument` like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$content = "
    <script>
    [random] string 1
    </script>

    <script>
    [random] string 2
    </script>
    ....
    <script>
    [random] string n
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    must keeping script
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    must keeping script
    </script>    
";

$dom->loadHTML($content);
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    if (!$script->hasAttributes()) {
        echo $script->nodeValue . "<br>";
    }
}
```

This will output:

[random] string 1
[random] string 2
[random] string n

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
 $text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
 echo strip_tags($text);

 ?>
```

to get more info about strip tags see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

If the content is of string type then you can use [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [str-ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

Answer (score 0):

Then try strip_tags function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php?

Answer (score 0):

if the file is test.txt, use this code

```
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 5000);
echo str_replace("</script>","",str_replace("<script>","",$theData));
fclose($fh);
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but lost </script> of other script I must keep such as: <script type="text/javascript">must keeping</script>