# remove tag but keep content between tag if matched string

Tags: php, match, remove-if

I have file php:

```
<?php
$content = "
<script>
include string show_ads_1 and other string 1
</script>

<script>
include string show_ads_2 and other string 2
</script>

<script>
include string show_ads_x and other string x
</script>

<script>
not include 'show  _  ads  _  x' --> keeping this
</script>

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
include string 'show_ads_x' but keeping this because <script type='text/javascript'> not <script>
</script>
";

//Only remove tag <script></script> if includes "show_ads" string
$content = preg_replace('/(<script>)(show_ads.*?)(<\/script>)/s', '$2', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

If content between `<script>...</script>` include string "show_ads_" it will remove `<script>` and `</script>` but keep all content.

But above script is not working. Nothing removed.
I want when run it and view source code it looks like:

```
include string show_ads_1 and other string 1



include string show_ads_2 and other string 2



include string show_ads_x and other string x


<script>
not include 'show  _   ads  _  x' --> keeping this
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
include string 'show_ads_x' but keeping this because <script type='text/javascript'> not <script>
</script>
```

Comment: And how does this "not work"? Your view source sample shows that the script tags HAVE been removed, as you state in your requirements.

Comment: @MarcB I think what hes trying to get at; when you view over the source code the `<script> </script` tags are not visible, essentially just not adding them into the source code; but the javascript still behaves it's inside the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Possible Duplication of own question maybe? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738376/remove-tag-but-keep-string-between-tag-in-php

Comment: @Marc B: Run file and see blank page. View source code, nothing changed.

I want page shows:
"include string show_ads_1 and other string 1"
"include string show_ads_2 and other string 2"
"include string show_ads_n and other string n"

View source code not include <script> in above and </script> in below

Comment: @Daryl Gill: No sir, that question is solved but remove all <script>...</script>. I want only remove if include string. I will delete old question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<script>)(show_ads.*?)(<\/script>)/s', '$2', $content);
```

With:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<script>)([^<]*show_ads_[^<]*)(<\/script>)/s', '$2', $content);
```

Comment: WOW, thanks snipes83. It works better because I get content from other site.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) to perform that, like this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$content = "
    <script>
    include string show_ads_1 and other string 1
    </script>

    <script>
    include string show_ads_2 and other string 2
    </script>
    ....
    <script>
    include string show_ads_x and other string x
    </script>

    <script>
    include string bla bla bla
    </script>

    <script>
    not include 'show  _   ads  _  x' --> keeping this
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    must keeping script
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    include string 'show_ads_x' but keeping this because <script type='text/javascript'> not <script>
    </script>    
";

$dom->loadHTML($content);
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

foreach ($scripts as $script) {
    if (!$script->hasAttributes()) {
        if (strstr($script->nodeValue, "show_ads_")) {
            echo $script->nodeValue . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$script->nodeValue</script>" . "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```