# How to stop displaying html tags in frontEnd/browser in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys i am using **[tinymice](https://www.tinymce.com/)** , in my laravel admin panel that i have created, earlier this was just a textbox , so i would get content that looked like so:

```
I have a lovely garden in my house and i love it
```

Now with this richtextbox i get content stored in my table columb that looks like so:

```
<p>I Love Eggs and i&nbsp;Also Love to eat hame.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Yeah Danm ! hahah Thats funny.</strong></p>
```

I have the following code running in my view file:

```
@foreach($recentPost as $recent)

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="indi-news-highlight-box">
            <a href="{!!  route('getArticle' , ['id' => $recent->id ]) !!}">
                <img src="{{ URL::asset('images/temp/blog-post-image.jpg') }}" alt="{!!  $recent->title  !!}">
            </a>
            <div class="content-box">
                <h3>
                    <a href="{!!  route('getArticle' , ['id' => $recent->id ]) !!}">
                        {{  $recent->title }}
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                    {{ $recent->blog_content }}
                </p>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>   <!-- End col-md-6 -->

@endForEach
```

The below part outputs the description which was grabbed from richtextbox:

```
<p>{{ $recent->blog_content }}</p>
```

Now i get the following in my frontEnd:

[image]

As you can see the HTML tags are output in the view itself , how do i prevent this ?? How do i prevent the HTML from outputting in my view ??.

I don't want remove the html tags **[LIKE HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738376/remove-tag-but-keep-string-between-tag-in-php)** , I want to keep them , so i can do the styling in CSS , but i don't want the html tags displaying in my frontEnd , what is the solution to this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Display it as unescaped data** *link to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data)*

Blade is preventing `XSS` for you, but using the following syntax you can tell it not to do `XSS` prevention.

```
<p>{!! $recent->blog_content !!}</p>
```

Comment: thanks , will accept your answer ! :) that was easy :D .

Comment: Note that this is pretty bad practice, since anyone who can access your rich text editor can now execute JavaScript.

Comment: @Loek got it !! thanks :) , its a controlled environment , only i operate the admin panel :P , will give it a taught later , thanks for the heads up !!

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax

```
    {{}}
```

to

```
    {!! !!}
```

that is to say

```
    {!! $recent->blog_content !!}
```